# View results of pl/sql stored procedure in Toad?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad, toad-data-point

I'm new to Oracle, and I use `Toad Data Point` to create and test stored procedures.

I created this simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dummy_sp (
                      p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN 
  OPEN p_recordset FOR
      select sysdate, user from dual;
END dummy_sp ;
/
```

I executed this, and the result from Toad is `Executed Successfully`.

Now, I would like to view the results of this stored procedure. In `Toad Data Point` I type the following:

```
variable mycursor refcursor;
call dummy_sp ( :mycursor );
```

I  get a popup asking for a parameter. I click OK and I get the error `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`.

How can I see the result of SP `dummy_sp` in `Toad Data Point`?

In `SQL Server` I can run `exec usp_sales` and see the results of a `select` statement. There has to be something like that in `Oracle` and `Toad`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, using **Toad Data Point**.

Execute the stored procedure with a bind variable in it, like `:mycursor`, and then make sure to configure the type as `CURSOR` and direction as `OUT` when Toad Data Point prompts you for the bind variable settings.

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]

Finally, if you wish to avoid the popup for bind variables, you can execute the procedure directly from the object explorer:

Right-click the procedure and choose **Operations** / **Execute Procedure**, and Toad will run it, without prompting for data type.

Comment: Thanks so much. That's a lot of work just to test a stored procedure.

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf, Indeed, working with record sets as parameters or results in Oracle is not as easy as it could be. Anyway, if you found this answer useful, consider accepting it so that it would also help others.

Comment: You're right. One last question: Is there any way to bypass the popup `Bind variables`?

Comment: Maybe declare `mycursor` after the `BEGIN`? That way the additional step of selecting the `Type` and `Direction` in the `Bind Variables` popup is eliminated?

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf, I figured it out. You can execute the procedure directly from the object explorer panel, and Toad Data Point will automatically build the wrapper and do the bind without a popup. I have edited my answer to include this at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a workaround while you wait for help with your tool, [the default, free IDE for Oracle Database](https://www.oracle.com/sqldeveloper) makes this pretty easy.

If you execute the program using the code editor, it will automatically grab any outputs, whether those be OUT params or RETURNs from a function, including your refcursor

[image]

Or if your GUI has proper SQLPlus script execution support (SQL Developer does, not sure about your program):

```
var x refcursor
exec dummy_sp(:x);
print :x;
```

And the output:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.



SYSDATE             USER                                                                                                                            
------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
27-JUN-19  13.58.47 HR
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I prefer using Toad Data Point since that's the tool the company purchased for this.

Comment: Like I said, a workaround. Remember, your company bought Oracle first...and this is part of that investment.

Comment: You're right. How would I execute the stored procedure with `SQL Developer`? I've tried `exec dummy_sp ( :mycursor );` and `call dummy_sp`, but they all return errors.

Comment: Click the green play button, you'll see the code we run to execute your procedure.

Comment: I _know_ the green play button executes _stuff_. I created the SP in Toad so the `create or replace` is not in `SQL Developer`.

Comment: What code would I execute in `SQL Developer` to view the results of that existing SP?